# How to add and subtract hours and minutes

Tags: java, android, time, hour, minute

I have some problems. I am a beginner programmer. I need to create an application like a clock with Android Studio and need to add and subtract hours and minutes. When I press the +1H will need to add 1H to take the same with +1M and -1M and I can't coordinate how can I do that.
I am doing so that when the clock reached 23:59 again, it was 00:00 and so cyclically

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button,button2,button3,button4;
    private TextView textView;
    int hour = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.res);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (hour >= 9) {
                        textView.setText((++hour + "") + ":" + "00");
                    } else {
                        textView.setText("0" + (++hour + "") + ":" + "00");
                    }

            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(hour>=9) {
                    textView.setText((--hour + "") + ":" + "00");
                }else{
                    textView.setText("0"+(--hour + "") + ":" + "00");
                }
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(minute>=9) {
                    textView.setText("00" + ":" + (++minute + ""));
                }else{
                    textView.setText("00" + ":" + "0"+(++minute + ""));
                }
            }
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(minute>=9) {
                    textView.setText("00" + ":" + (--minute + ""));
                }else{
                    textView.setText("00" + ":" + "0"+(--minute + ""));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the Calendar class? It takes care of most of these things for you. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)

Answer (score 3):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

All of this functionality already exists. Use `LocalTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Here’s a short demonstration with output given in comments:

```
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(23, 59);
    System.out.println(time); // 23:59
    time = time.minusHours(1);
    System.out.println(time); // 22:59
    time = time.minusMinutes(1);
    System.out.println(time); // 22:58
    time = time.plusHours(1);
    System.out.println(time); // 23:58
    time = time.plusMinutes(1);
    System.out.println(time); // 23:59
    time = time.plusHours(1);
    System.out.println(time); // 00:59
    time = time.plusMinutes(1);
    System.out.println(time); // 01:00
```

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [`Calendar#add`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#add(int,%2520int)) for this. Confusingly, you can use it to both add and subtract.

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); //A calendar set to the current time
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1); //Add one hour
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1); //Subtract one hour
```

When it comes to printing times, the default option on API versions < 24 is to uuse a [`DateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat). So, instead of trying to determine it yourself:

```
final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); //hours and minutes, 24hr clock
textView.setText(format.format(calendar.getTime());
```

However, do note there are issues with `SimpleDateFormat`, particularly when it comes to multithreading. As Ole V.V. has suggested in the comments, you should consider using the [`ThreeTenABP`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library instead.

If you're targeting API 24+, you can make use of the Java 8 additions around time in the `java.time` package, like `Instant` and `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: I do recommend java.time, added in Java 8. You may also use it at lower API levels since it has been backported in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, this is good advice, thank you - I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will help you to get the time and get it incremented or decremented properly.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(yourdate);
int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(hours>=9)
        {
            hours=hours+1;
            textView.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            textView.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        }
    }
});
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(hours>=9)
        {
            hours=hours-1;
            textView.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            textView.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        }
    }
});
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(minutes>=9)
        {
            minutes=minutes+1;
            textView.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            textView.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        }
    }
});
b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(minutes>=9)
        {
            minutes=mminutes-1;
            textView.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            textView.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: how do I do so when the clock reaches 23:59 and when I press +1H or +1M it was 00:00 and how to do that the Clock does not exceed the mark 23 and the minute 59 on Android studio

Answer (score 0):

To add or minus 30 minutes in current time in Kotlin language:

```
    val timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss", Locale.US)
    val date = Date()
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c.time = date
    //30 for add 30 minutes or -30 to minus 30 minutes
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -30)
    val timeMinus30 = c.time
    val timeInString = timeFormat.format(timeMinus30)
```